# VBA converts number into scientific notation when writing to csv file

Tags: excel, vba, csv, scientific-notation

I have an Excel worksheet that contains data such as shown below:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Paul | Johnson | New York | 0 | FALSE |
| CoordX | 90 | 0.08348590975457270 |  |  |

I need to write this to a csv file.

The .SaveAs method isn't working for me as this would create 2 trailing commas for row 2.

My approach therefore is:
- For each row in the worksheet I determine the last column containing data;
- Then I create a string of all cells in that row;
- That string is written to a file.

The relevant part of the code looks like:

```
fileLine = sCat(Range(ws.Cells(rLoop, 1), ws.Cells(rLoop, maxCols + 1)), ",")
Print #fileNumber, fileLine
```

where sCat is the following function:

```
Function sCat(vP As Variant, delim As String) As String

    ' Concatenate all cells in a range, delimited by delim.
    Dim v
    Dim delim2 As String
    
    For Each v In vP
        sCat = sCat & delim2 & v
        delim2 = delim
    Next v
End Function
```

The data in my output csv file looks like:

[image: Output file]

Thus the number 0.08348590975457270 end up  as 8.348590975457270E-2. How can I avoid the scientific notation appearing in the csv file (without having to play around with the formatting of the cells in the worksheet)?

I was advised to try:

```
fileLine = sCat(Application.Trim(Range(ws.Cells(rLoop, 1), ws.Cells(rLoop, maxCols + 1))), ",")
```

but this only partially worked. Most numbers didn't get converted into scientific notation anymore. However, there were a couple of numbers that were still in scientific notation. Quite erratic behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a numeric check and formatting:

```vb
Function sCat(vP As Variant, delim As String) As String
    ' Concatenate all cells in a range, delimited by delim.
    Dim v
    Dim delim2 As String
    
    For Each v In vP
        If IsNumeric(v) Then
            If v <> Int(v) Then
                'check for non-integer numbers only
                v = Format(v, "0.0#################################")
            End If
        End If
        sCat = sCat & delim2 & v
        delim2 = delim
    Next v
End Function
```

`Format(v, "0.##################################")` forces the full set of digits.

Comment: Thanks. It resolved the issue around scientific notation. But now any integer value in the spreadsheet has a dot added. For example 20231031 now becomes 20231031. in my csv file. How do I avoid the additional dot for integer values?

Comment: I updated the code. Integer values are not formatted

Comment: That is producing the output as I required. Thanks.